# Pi and h-bridge power issue

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, bridge

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/b4uhh_j8uR0) tutorial in my attempt to create my first Pi based robot.

I am using a Pi 3 model B and I believe I have things wired up correctly however while the H-Bridge is powered up, the Pi isn't.

The Pi's LED actually does switch on **but** it is **not** listed on my routers IP addresses list. As a result I can't SSH into it.

However, if I plug the Pi independently into power it responds and works as expected.

Can anyone help, please?
There's a screen shot below incase it helps.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a Pi 5V pin connected to the motor driver board?  The motor driver board may be generating 5V from the motor supply unless you have removed a particular jumper from the motor driver board.  You will then have the two 5V supplies fighting each other.

Comment: Connect a screen and and check what it shows. If it shuts down, then use a proper power supply and enable boot up logs to see whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those batteries simply can't handle driving the entire RPi3 + H-bridge + motors. The batteries are [each rated](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/ca6795215fab44730055055910f21b49.pdf) at `2.85 Ah`, but RPi3 alone, need a constant power supply of not less than ~2A. Either use a RPi0 or another battery, such as those for mobile phones.

I bet if you connect a screen to that pi, the low power flash would be shown.

Comment: My Pi3 powers quite happily from about half an amp.  You only need more if you are using power hungry peripherals.

Comment: Thanks. I thought as much. It's just that the tutorial didn't explicitly mentioned powering the Pi separately.
Then I got confused when I saw the Pi flickering to life from the connection to the battery pack